# Syntax Error in INSERT INTO using OdbcConnection

Tags: sql, ms-access

I get `4200 Syntax Error` when I execute this code for a MS Access database:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(@"Dsn=ani;dbq=D:\anita\inventory\chemicals.accdb;defaultdir=D:\anita\inventory;driverid=25;fil=MS Access;maxbuffersize=2048;pagetimeout=5;uid=admin"))
        {
          conn.Open();
          string CommandText = "INSERT INTO SupplierDetails (ID, Supplier, Company, Address, State, Country, Pincode, PhoneNo, MobileNo, Email, Fax, RawMaterials, Note) VALUES (@ID, @Supplier, @Company, @Address, @State, @Country, @Pincode, @PhoneNo, @MobileNo, @Email, @Fax, @RawMaterials, @Note)";

            using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(CommandText, conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", TextBox3.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Supplier", TextBox4.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Company", TextBox1.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", TextBox11.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", TextBox2.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", TextBox5.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pincode", TextBox10.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhoneNo", TextBox6.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MobileNo", TextBox7.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", TextBox8.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fax", TextBox9.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RawMaterials", TextBox12.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Note", TextBox13.Text);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you have the relevant namespaces ? 
( also please provide more details.  p.s. welcome to SO).

Comment: ya m having relevant namespacs

Comment: which line do you get the error?

Comment: Have you already checked whether the connection string is correct? That is, can you e.g. successfully execute a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SupplierDetails` query on the same connection (after you open it & before the `INSERT`)?

Comment: Is ID an Autoincrement column? If so, then leave out the column and value

Comment: @steve i dont think that would cause syntax error

Comment: Just comment everything after line conn.open and see if you are able to open connection

Comment: ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement. Error at dis line :Line 53:                 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: It is working for Update, Select and delete query

Comment: And ID is Autoincremented

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The field named `NOTE` has the same name of a [reserved keyword](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321266) in JET 4.0.
Encapsulate it with square brackets

```
string CommandText = "INSERT INTO SupplierDetails (ID, Supplier, Company, Address, " + 
                     "State, Country, Pincode, PhoneNo, MobileNo, Email, Fax, " + 
                     "RawMaterials, [Note]) VALUES (@ID, @Supplier, @Company, @Address, " + 
                     "@State, @Country, @Pincode, @PhoneNo, @MobileNo, @Email, " + 
                     "@Fax, @RawMaterials, @Note)";
```

**EDIT** I see you are using an `OdbcConnection`, this will require that your parameters placeholders will be supplied using question marks, not strings with @ prefix. So your CommandText should be:

```
string CommandText = "INSERT INTO SupplierDetails (Supplier, Company, Address, " + 
                     "State, Country, Pincode, PhoneNo, MobileNo, Email, Fax, " + 
                     "RawMaterials, [Note]) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```

Note how I have removed also the ID field and its parameter placeholder because you say it is an AutoIncrement field and therefore you can't pass your own value for that.
Also remember that, in this scenario, the parameters are recognized by their position in the Parameter collection. Thus it is very important to add them in the correct order expected by the commandText.

Comment: After adding square brackets around Note it is showing : ERROR [07002] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 13.

Comment: Leave out the autoincrement field, it is calculated by Access not by you.

Comment: Even after removing this line    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", TextBox3.Text); it is showing the same error i.e.ERROR [07002] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 13.

Comment: Got it, using an ODBC connection, you can't use named parameters in the sql text, replace everything with question marks. I will update the answer