# Create a temporary table and then Select

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have the following problem in an WPF application written in c#. I need to create some temporary tables on an sql server, do some joins from within the app an then select from the joined table. In the statistical language R I simply create two SQL Queries (one containing the #tables and one with the final select statement from a merge of several #tables) and execute them one after another. Doing the query in just one Query only returns NULL after the #temp tables have been created.

This is SQL statement #1:

```
DECLARE @from_time Date;
DECLARE @to_time Date;

CREATE TABLE #temp1
     (
person_id float,
first_name varchar(100),
othercols...
) 


INSERT INTO #temp1
SELECT DISTINCT
   person_id, first_name, ...
FROM
campus.v_exam_registration_context context
FULL JOIN
campus.v_exam_timetable time
ON
CAST(context.examination_date AS DATETIME) = time.timetable_date
AND
context.examination_time_from = time.time_from
AND
context.examination_time_to = time.time_to  

CREATE TABLE #temp2
(
exam_event_id float,
person_id float, 
othercols...
)  


INSERT INTO #temp2
SELECT DISTINCT
exam_event_id, person_id, excused, excused_reason, missed, modify_date, study_id, study_name,
person_exam_id, exam_in_course_id, subject, subject_unicode, personal_exam_no, exam_points, grade_description
FROM
campus.v_person_exam exam
WHERE
exam.person_id
IN
(
SELECT
  #temp1.person_id
  FROM
    #temp1
  WHERE
    #temp1.attempt_counter > 1
  AND
    #temp1.timetable_date > @from_time 
  AND
    #temp1.timetable_date < @to_time
  )  

  CREATE TABLE #temp3
  (
  person_id float,
  first_name varchar(100),
) 

INSERT INTO #temp3
SELECT 
#temp2.person_id, first_name, last_name, matriculation_number, attempt_counter, timetable_date, examination_date, semester, course_number, course_name, 
exam_name, exam_type, component_name, course_area, module_number, module_name, credits, 
FROM 
#temp2
LEFT JOIN 
#temp1
ON
#temp2.person_id = #temp1.person_id
AND
#temp2.exam_event_id = #temp1.exam_event_id
WHERE
#temp1.course_name IS NOT NULL
```

And this is #2:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.* 
FROM 
#temp3 T1
INNER JOIN  
(
 SELECT * 
 FROM 
    #temp3  
 WHERE 
    #temp3.attempt_counter > 1
 AND
    #temp3.exam_points > 4
 AND
    #temp3.timetable_date > @from_time
 AND
    #temp3.timetable_date < @from_time
 ) as T2
 ON
  T1.person_id = T2.person_id
 AND 
  T1.exam_name = T2.exam_name
 ORDER BY T1.last_name ASC, T1.course_name DESC, T1.timetable_date ASC
```

But now I'm required to translate the R Script into a standalone exe-file. 
Here is my code block in c#:

```
    private void queryButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

    {

        List<Student> temp = new List<Student>();
        string pass = @pass_box.Password;
        string dsn = "CampusNet";
        String ConnectionString =
            "DSN=" + dsn + ";" +
            "UID=" + uid + ";" +
            "PWD=" + pass;

        OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(ConnectionString);
        using (conn)
        {
            if (conn.State.ToString() == "Open")
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
            try
            {
                conn.Open();

                var command = new OdbcCommand(sqlcommand, conn); \\sqlcommand is read from a textfile
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@from_time", from_time);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@to_time", to_time);
                command.CommandTimeout = 120;
                var resultCommand = command.ExecuteNonQuery(); 

                var query = new OdbcCommand(sqlquery, conn); \\sqlquery is read from a textfile
                query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@from_time", from_time);
                query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@to_time", to_time);
                var resultQuery = query.ExecuteReader();

                Results_Box.AppendText(resultQuery.HasRows.ToString());
                while (resultQuery.Read())
                {  
        temp.Add(new Student{
            name = !result.IsDBNull(3) ? result.GetString(3) : null
        });
                    Results_Box.AppendText("Test"); \\only for testing purposes, works if I select from existing table
                }
                resultQuery.Close();
                results = temp;

                Results_Box.Document.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(
                    new Run("There are " + temp.Count().ToString() + " Hits")));   
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Connected");
                conn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception E)
            {
                Results_Box.Document.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run("Connection failed")));
                Results_Box.Document.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run(E.ToString())));
            }

        }
    }
```

I'm new to c#, so it seems that the first query is executed but deleted immediately afterwards and the second select statement returns 0 hits. If I select from non-temporary tables everything works fine. Since the first query has a duration approximately equal to the respective R-Query (25 sec), I suspect that the first one is correctly executed, but immediately deleted or the second query starts before the first is finished. Creating one combined query does not work neither in R nor in c#. I would like to stick to temporary tables rather than using ##tables, if possible.

Is there a special method to use for creating temp tables in c#? `conn.open()` is open during the whole runtime of `using (conn){...}` ?

Comment: Look at using a sql server stored procedure, then calling this once from a command.execute("exec mycommand")

Comment: This is strange. I would expect the dropping of the temp tables at the closing of the connection. (yes unless you close it the connection is open until you exit from the using block). I suggest to try using the proper classes to interact with sql server and not the Odbc ones. (Use SqlConnection, etc...)

Comment: Also remove the AddWithValue call and use the proper Add(name, type).Value approach to set the parameters. [AddWithValue is full of surprises](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) particularly when using dates

Comment: @SteveFord Thanks for your advice, I will take a look at server stored procedures. Hopefully our department will have the required permissions to create those procedures. Else I will try to use the correct classes as

Comment: Here I found a possible solution: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15596630/syntax-error-in-insert-into-using-odbcconnection). It seems that  `@parameter` in the sql command must be replaced with `?` when using ODBC connections. I will try that as soon as possible and share the result.